# スタックオーバーフロ ーさせたい時の入力の順番

Tags: メモリ管理, スタック

CTFチャレンジブックという本を勉強しているのですが、44バイト分のスタックがありスタックオーバーフロー によって printf を実行したい場合、入力が

```
echo -e 'AAAA....AA(44個のA)\x50\x83\x04\x08(左4つは関数アドレス、printfのアドレス)BBBB(<-printf呼び出し後のリターンアドレス 、ダミー)\x60\xa0\x04\x08(左4つは引数、バッファ変数)' | ./(バッファに入力を読み込むファイル)
```

となっています。以下に簡潔なバージョンを書きます。

```
echo -e 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x50\x83\x04\x08BBBB\x60\xa0\x04\x08' | ./(バッファに入力を読み込むファイル)
```

この時、本の説明では上位アドレスから低位アドレスに向かって、引数（バッファ変数）--> ダミー --> 関数アドレス（printfのアドレス)のように積み上げるとなっています。

ここで疑問なのですが、なぜ入力の時に(AAA...A)-->(printfのアドレス)-->ダミー-->（バッファ変数）の順番でechoしているのでしょうか？つまり

```
echo -e 'AAAA....AA(44個のA)\x50\x83\x04\x08(左4つは関数アドレス、printfのアドレス)BBBB(<-printf呼び出し後のリターンアドレス 、ダミー)\x60\xa0\x04\x08(左4つは引数、バッファ変数)' | ./(バッファに入力を読み込むファイル)
```

この順番なのでしょうか？本の説明の通りに積み上げるのであればスタックのFILO構造を考えると(AA...A)-->(バッファ変数) --> ダミー --> (printfのアドレス)の順番にechoする文字列をつなげないといけない気がします。

Comment: 多分あなたが試したいのは「スタックオーバーフロー」ではなくて「バッファオーバーフロー」なんでしょう。ミスリーディングです。

Comment: 今の質問内容だと当該書籍を持っていない人（オイラなど）にとっては質疑応答が全く成立しません。アタックテストの設問自体の引用が無いと回答することはできないでしょう。ですがそこまで書いちゃうと引用の範囲を超える可能性もあり @Nis さんにとってリスクがあります。また、この手のアタック方法の解説を行うこと自体がなんとか幇助になったりすると回答者側にリスクがあります。要するにこういうクラック系の質問は訊くほうも答えるほうもリスクがあるので、こういう掲示板系サイトではあまり好まれません。回答を得るのは難しいかも。

Comment: スタックと、ローカル変数の使い方の参考 
 https://brain.cc.kogakuin.ac.jp/~kanamaru/lecture/MP/final/part06/node9.html   恐らく、ローカル変数として宣言した文字列ヘ、長い文字列をコピーして、スタック上の戻りアドレスを書き換える、脆弱性のある行儀の悪いサンプルプログラムが前提ですよね？今どき、文字列の長さを確認しない文字コピー使ってる人いるんですかね。

Comment: バッファオーバーフロー脆弱性のあるサンプルコードが挙げてあるのでアタックしてみてください、というコンテストを書籍化しているのだと書名から推定。詳細解説しろと言われればオイラでもできますけど、この質問文だけでは無理。